# CodeIgniter upload png image type not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

what my problem is why my code unable to store .png file in database and uploads folder, but other than file like .jpg, .gif I successfully insert to database and uploads folder, I had include `$config['allowed_types'] = 'png'` as well, in addition, here is what I var_dump out the error message "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." , Any idea how to solve my problem?

here is my code:

```
$upload_file_name = '';

$config['upload_path'] = '/var/www/html/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|gif|png';
$config['max_size'] = 100000;
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('receipt_attachment'))
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $errormessage = $this->upload->display_errors();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $errormessage);
    redirect('home/add_product');
}else{
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $upload_file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
}
```

thanks

Comment: may be your file extension is in capitals PNG, that might also cause problem sometimes...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this thread regarding invalid mime type?
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/204725/

Basically it might be (depending on your version of CI) that you have the older un-patched version that has trouble interpreting some png mime-types.

Take a read and try those solutions, and/or update to the newest CI code.

Comment: thank jakub, I had update my CI, the problem really because of my Old CI version that why png file unable uploaded.

Comment: good to hear, remember always update your CI codebase, it is very easy to do as the `/application` dir (where you have your code) never needs to be updated, typically it is just your `/system` folder

Answer (score 2):

Find mimes.php file inside config folder and add mime type ‘text/plain’ inside png array as follows.

```
'png'   =>   array('image/png',  'image/x-png','text/plain'),
```

Source Reff: 
http://www.genuinescope.com/blog/2012/06/codeigniter-upload-gives-error-file-type-not-allowed-for-png-images/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the date of your post, I assume you run CodeIgniter 2.1.0.

There is a documented issue with the upload class in CI 2.1.0 with PNGs (line 1058 in Upload system library), which was not present in previous versions, nor future.

Best way:
Update to 2.1.2 or at least use the system/libraries/Upload.php file from 2.1.2 (that did the trick for me).